# Java Issue: If/Else

Tags: java

I have made a program to tell what season it is based on the month. However, no matter what i input, it says that it is Fall. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SeasonChecker {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What month is it??");
    String month = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(month);
    if (month == "december"||month == "January"||month=="February"){
        System.out.println("Then it is Winter?");
    }
    else if (month=="March"||month=="May"||month=="April"){
        System.out.println("Then it is Spring!!!");

    }
    else if (month=="June"||month=="July"||month=="August"){
        System.out.println("Then it is Summer!");

    }
    else {

        System.out.println("Then it is Autumn!");

    }
    input.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Don't compare string values with `==`; that compares object references to determine if they're the same object.  Use `equals` to compare string values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
month == "december"||month == "January"
```

use `equals()` method while comparing `Strings`.

Example:

```
   "december".equals(month) || "January".equals(month)
```

`==` checks for reference equality (both references pointing to same object are not). `equals()` checks for content of the object.

Comment: I prefer this answer because it avoids nullpointerexceptions if `month` is null.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, with strings, you should use the `equals` method to make comparison, not the literal `==` comparison. So `month.equals("January")` Using `==` will compare the memory references and see if they are the same reference for objects. `==` is meant for comparing literals like int or double

Answer (score 2):

use equals method instead of ==

```
if (month.equals("december")||month.equals("January")||month.equals("February")){
```

in java == compares the reference. But equals method compares the value of String.